# Android facebook SSO- Verifying user is logged in server side

Tags: android, facebook

Friends!

I'm developing an android app which has a server component (done in rails). I need a way of authenticating the users are logged in (on the phone) when they upload or download things from the server, but I can't quite figure out how this should be done using the facebook APIs.

Hopefully there is a simple way to do this with the access_token, but I've not found it yet! The documentation is for the most part not written with the android crowd in mind.

Thanks for your time.

Edit: I can add, one way which might work (I don't know how to do a https request in rails right now), but doesn't feel like its intended, is to call the following address from the server and check that the response is valid:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXX

Comment: Can you clarify the use case? are you looking for a way to validate the identity of the user to make sure it's your app user that communicates with your server? or is it something else?